# Conditional Variation of \headheight

Tags: header-footer, conditionals

I'm trying to use `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package to vary the size of `\headheight` within a document. I'd like this to be larger for the first page and then smaller for each subsequent page.

I had thought I could accomplish this using code like the following in my preamble.

```
\ifthenelse{\thepage=1}
  {\setlength\headheight{72pt}}
  {\setlength\headheight{14pt}}
```

Unfortunately, that's not working for some reason. Below is some code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%% Margins %%%%

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}

%%%% Packages %%%%

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=Fit]{hyperref}

%%%% Headers/Footers %%%%

\setlength\headheight{72pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{{\color{BrickRed} \hrule height 1pt width\headwidth}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.65}

\lhead{\ifthenelse{\thepage = 1}
              {\textcolor{light-gray}{My Name} \\ [4ex] \vspace{36pt} \textcolor{light-gray}{Telephone Number}}
              {\textcolor{light-gray}{My Name}}}

\rhead{\ifthenelse{\thepage = 1}
              {\textcolor{light-gray}{Page \thepage \ of \zpageref{LastPage}} \\ [4ex] \vspace{36pt}
               \textcolor{light-gray}{Email Address}}
              {\textcolor{light-gray}{Page \thepage \ of \zpageref{LastPage}}}}

\chead{\ifthenelse{\thepage = 1}
              {{\large\bfseries MY NAME, TITLE} \\
               Address Line 2 \\
               Address Line 3 \\
               Address Line 4 \\ [1ex]}
              {}}

\cfoot{}

%%%% Main Document %%%%

\begin{document}

Some text

\newpage
\setlength\headheight{14pt}

More text

\end{document}
```

This code produces the desired output. The drawback though is that I need to manually specify where the first page break should occur and then reset the headheight using:

```
\newpage
\setlength\headheight{14pt}
```

Is there some way to automate this, using `\ifthenelse` or some other means? Setting things manually when the contents of the first page change doesn't require much effort, but I'd like to understand what's going wrong and how to do this properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.